# openGL render targets not working after certain number

Tags: opengl

I am binding multiple targets to a FBO. I have done a very simple operation here and it works. As you can notice I attach 3 targets (not showing here) and then 5 more which are stored in an array. I then do some computation and store the final image to render in the last position of m_rsm_indirect. Everything works fine and the final pass simply takes all the elements from 0 to 4 of m_rsm_indirect and sums them into the fifth one. Everything works if I use less elements, but if I increase the size by 1 and use the last element, no matter what I do, I always get a black image with a coupe of white horizontal stripes. Do I hit the limit of render targets? I tried to use glGetInteger with GL_MAX_RENDER etc but I get a negative number.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        glGenTextures(1, &m_rsm_indirect[i]);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_rsm_indirect[i]);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, WindowWidth, WindowHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    }

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_fbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_fbo);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_rsm, 0);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_rsm_color, 0);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_rsm_pos, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3_EXT+i, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_rsm_indirect[i], 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems very likely that you're exceeding the limit of render targets supported by your GPU. These limits are often powers of 2, and 8 is a common value for the number of supported render targets.

You can retrieve the supported number of render targets with:

```
GLint maxTargets = 0;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_DRAW_BUFFERS, &maxTargets);
```

Comment: yep, maxTarget is 8. So how am I supposed to do accumulation if I only have 8 targets? Should I use a texture array?